# Solve on parametric equation produces inequal results

Tags: equation-solving, computational-geometry, parametric-functions

I have a parametric (parameter t) equation in two dimensions (vectors).

```
s  = Solve[pt[t] == qt[t], {a, b}]
```

Both pt and qt are parametric lines using a and b as their parameter and a third parameter t which is the same on both and should stay in the result.
They are defined as

```
p[t_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t]}
q[t_] := {3 + Cos[-t], 3 + Sin[-t]}
pt[t_] := p[t] + a p'[t]
qt[t_] := q[t] + b q'[t]
```

The solve function should give the two parameters a and b as functions of t. This works, but the problem is that the resulting functions when using the a and b for qt and pt are not the same. For example even though the equation clearly says that pt[8] == qt[8] this isn't the case.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Please specify `pt` and `qt` in the question.  Presumably, they are functions of `a` and `b`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Is it better like that? Should I upload the notebook?

Comment: No need to upload notebook.  What you provided seems adequate.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, they are equal.  Redefine

```
s = First@Solve[pt[t] == qt[t], {a, b}]
(* {a -> 1/2 (-3 Csc[t] + 3 Sec[t] - 2 Tan[t]), 
    b -> 1/2 (3 Csc[t] + 3 Sec[t] - 2 Tan[t])} *)
```

to eliminate the extra set of brackets.  Then, for any value of `t`

```
FullSimplify[(pt[t] /. s) - (qt[t] /. s)]
(* {0, 0} *)
```

Comment: Interesting! I get another result with exactly the same parameters. I'll see if yours does help.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your results instantly worked. Now I just have to figure out what is wrong with my notebook/environment.